# Excel: Arrange data for a number of column based on unsorted column

Tags: excel

I have 4 Column of data as below ;

```
A  B   C     E   F   G
1  99  98    2 
2  97  94    3
3  93  92    1
```

A,B, C is a references column. I would like to grab the X and Y value in column B and C based on sequences in data E. 
(To simplify the question. i would like to re-arrange B,C data to sequence like column E)

I need to know how to do this because i need to plot a link of city coordinate based on given sequence. (unsorted).

Comment: Thanks Renaud for editing the question. got the answer already ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column F, put this:

```
=VLOOKUP($E2,$A$2:$C$4,2)
```

In column G, put this:

```
=VLOOKUP($E2,$A$2:$C$4,3)
```

Comment: Great just modify the formula a bit since i am referring to E column =VLOOKUP($E2,$A$2:$C$4,2)